# Change class based model to functional model React

Tags: javascript

I am using `class based models` in my `React Native and React applications` to easily parse data.

A model looks like this:

```
export default class ClassModel {
    constructor(id, title, value) {
        this.id = id
        this.title = title
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

As any `class based object` I initialised it like this in my `functional components`:

```
const classModel = new ClassModel(1, 'Title', someValue)
```

I am wondering, **is there any way to transform this class based model into a functional one?**

I know how to transform any `class` that returns some `UI` but I `can't find a way to transform a model`.

Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with react?

Comment: mostly because I am using this in my react/react-native applications and I am trying to write my code 100% in functional components and hooks

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be related to react? `new ClassModel` is not how react components are made?

Comment: `class Welcome extends React.Component ` is how a react class based component is made, but my problem is with models objects, that does not return some UI, but are helping me to parse my data

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Using a `class` is a useful way to represent models and data.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I am trying to write my code 100% in functional components, and i couldn't find a way to transform a class based model, into a functional one (if this is possible tho)
If this is not possible, my apologies for wasting your time guys, and i will remove the question

Comment: A model isn't a component. Functional react components are generally better than class-based components, but that doesn't mean classes don't have their place.

Comment: You can convert that class to a plain object (`{id, title, value}`) and instead of methods have free functions that act on such objects, but that has nothing to do with React.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan, indeed, is not a component, but just trying to understand if there is a way to make this transformation for models

Comment: There definitely is (see @AKX's comment), but it's not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your time, thought it was something more complicated or so
Just a rookie here trying to improve my JS understandings